# Gerund after ing form

Tags: grammar, gerunds

After transitive verbs like teach or learn we use a noun (phrase).
But can we also use a gerund (as they function like a noun) even in a progressive sentence?

Are these sentences correct?

> Tony is a driving instructor.
> He teaches driving. And now he's at
> work. He's teaching driving.

Comment: Tony is a loitering Pony. :)

Comment: @ lol Maybe I should change my example xD

Comment: Yes, they're correct. A gerund is an appropriate object for a transitive verb.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with using a gerund/participle phrase as an object, if the verb permits it. And if that verb can be used in a present continuous form then you can get "He is teaching driving" or "He's enjoying mowing the lawn" and so on. This particular combination of participles is going to be rare, but there is no grammar error, and the construction is valid.